# What solutions are there for getting HD video?

Tags: video, hd

What solutions are there, preferably single chip solutions, for getting HD video over DVI/HDMI?

My googling is not giving me much, only about the Blackfin chip from Analog.

I know about the Propellor from Parallax and that it can give SD video out easily, and how FPGA's can do it too, but other than those three I do not know of any other single chip solutions that can give me HD video over DVI/HDMI.

Comment: Are you just looking for something that can drive a 1080p monitor, or are you wanting video MPEG/h.264 processing too? What is your application?

Comment: I think a lot of devices respect HDCP DRM, be sure to look that up to make sure it won't break everything.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.
I am not interested in mpeg, just driving a display in HD. My application for this is putting a lot of information on a display at once, hence wanting HD instead of sd.

Comment: re: a lot of information: Text or images?

Comment: Just text at first, I would prefer to have the ability for putting in images later.

Comment: For specialized questions like this, now there is a new proposal at Areas 51: [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies?referrer=lxeiaDBzsJIqpGpL-P5bMg2) which focuses on Television and Broadcast in depth. Please join and invite others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spartan 6 FPGA certainly can drive HDMI/DVI signals directly, demonstrated in the [Atlys](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS) board. I've personally driven 1920x1200 VGA from a Spartan 3A starter kit, but the signal wasn't very clean then. You're looking at very high bandwidth signals, however, so the boards must be designed carefully.

If this is for a single hobbyist build, you might be better off using a premade graphics card with its own framebuffer, for instance a USB one. DisplayLink comes to mind.

Comment: We are inviting experts for specialized questions like this; now there is a new proposal at Areas 51: Broadcast and Media Technologies which focuses on Television and Broadcast in depth. Please join and invite others.

Answer (score 1):

An FPGA comes to mind. Jeri Ellsworth has demonstrated an FPGA driving a VGA monitor at 1024x768, which isn't HD, but it shouldn't be too much extra to reach 1280x720, or even 1920x1080. The problem you might encounter is that HDMI uses differential high speed signalling, and it's digital, unlike VGA, which is analog. With VGA, you might be able to get away with a bit of a noisy signal or high capacitive load... probably not so much with HDMI.

Comment: We are inviting experts for specialized questions like this; now there is a new proposal at Areas 51: Broadcast and Media Technologies which focuses on Television and Broadcast in depth. Please join and invite others.